# JTextPane selected text is deselected when the new text is written

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I used `JTextPane` to read logs which comes from telnet server. Problem is that when the new logs occurred and written to `JTextPane`, my selected text deselected I suppose that I should change default caret of `JTextPane` but I could not. Please give an any suggestion I want to preserve my selected text.

Comment: Do you mean the selected text gets overwritten or the selection disappears as everything gets deselected?

Comment: What method do you use to add your text? Could you give us a piece of code?

Comment: Only selection disappear everything gets de selected  i use insert string method of styleddocument for add text

Comment: **Disappears** mean is removed completely or scrolled out of the view? or just becomes deselected?

Comment: I am sorry disappear mean is deselected

Comment: It really deselected of visually? After the effect what's retuned by getSelectionStart/getSelectionEnd methods?

Comment: Deselected actually both getselection start and getselectionend is last character index

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultCaret caret=(DefaultCaret)theJTextPaneInstance.getCaret();  
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```

You can switch off the update policy.